# A question about finding proper linear subrepresentations of a linearized set.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Consider the group $S_n$ and the action on a linearized set of elements $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ $V= \{\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i\}$ (generated vector space).

I want to show that the representation

$$\varphi: S_n \rightarrow GL(V)$$

has exactly two proper (non-zero) subrepresentations and $V$ is their direct sum.

Now I know that if we can write $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $V$ is carrying a linear representation, then there exist $\varphi_1 \, , \, \varphi_2$ such that (with a little abuse of notation) , $\varphi_g = \varphi^{1}_g \oplus \varphi^2_g $ and $\varphi_g$ will be a block-diagonal matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}\varphi^1_g(v^{(1)}_1, \dots v^{(1)}_n) & 0 \\ 0 & \varphi^2_g(v^{(2)}_1, \dots v^{(2)}_n)\end{pmatrix}$$

But how can I find the proper subrepresentation in this case?

I would say that expressing $V$ as a direct sum in this case would yield just $V = V \oplus \{0\}$. But in this case I would have that one of subrepresentations is zero.

Comment: What is dimension of the ambient space ?

Comment: Since I'm considering an initial set of $v_1, \dots, v_n$ elements and then linearize by considering all sums and products by scalar, the generated vector space $V$ should have dimension $n$, right?

Comment: A question of vocabulary: instead of " linearize by considering all sums and products by scalar", say "take all linear combinations of..."

Comment: it's the same.. come on..

Comment: I am surprized by the way you answer. I only attempt to advise you small improvements...

Comment: I know ^^ sorry about that..